# Needing Clarity on SQL Join Query

Tags: sql

Having some trouble understanding this query, particularly the WHERE in the subquery. I don't really get what it is accomplishing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
# Find the largest country (by area) in each continent. Show the continent,
# name, and area.
SELECT continent, name, area
FROM countries AS a
WHERE area = (
 SELECT MAX(area)
 FROM countries AS b
 WHERE a.continent = b.continent
)
```

Comment: I know what you are asking is from a learning site, but don't remember which.  This has been asked many times before, but without knowing the site origin you are trying to learn from, can't find.  Try to do a search on that site name and see what answers already come up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following subset of the countries data:

```
Continent      Country    Area
North America   USA     3718691
North America   Canada  3855081
North America   Mexico  761602
Europe          France  211208
Europe          Germany 137846
Europe          UK      94525
Europe          Italy   116305
```

This is a correlated query that behaves as follows:

1. Reads the first row returned by the outer query (North America, USA, 3718691)
2. Runs the subquery which correlates to a.continent, North America, and returns 3855081 which is the maximum area in North America.
3. Does the where equality which checks to see if 3855081 matches the area on the row we're working on.
4. It doesn't match so the next row in the outer query is read and we start over at step 1 this time working on the second row.
5. Repeat for all rows in the outer query.

   When we're looking at rows 2 and 4, step 4. will match so those rows will be returned by the query.

   You can check the results by using this data in your countries table and running the query.

   Note that this is a very poor way to determine the country with the maximum area per continent because it repeats the subquery for every country.  Using my sample data, it determines the maximum area for North America 3 times and the maximum area for Europe 4 times.

Since you asked in your comment, I would write this query as follows:

```
SELECT a.continent, a.name, a.area
FROM countries AS a
     inner join (select continent, max(area) max_area
                 from countries
                 group by continent) as b on a.continent = b.continent
WHERE a.area = b.max_area
```

In this version of the query, the maximum for each continent is only determined once.  The original query was written to illustrate correlated queries and it's important to understand them.  Correlated queries can often be used to resolve complex logic.

Comment: This is very helpful and really appreciate the detail. What would be a more efficient way to run this query?

Comment: @jsc42 Added my version of the query to the answer

Comment: So by joining on a subquery, you're adding the subquery result to the countries as A table in one shot, without running it repeatedly? If so, that actually makes more sense to me.

Comment: @jsc42 Yes, that's right. Sometimes the optimizer will figure out how to do the work in one shot for a correlated query.  So in this case, the optimizer may rewrite the query close to my version for you.  But you can't depend on that.  You need to think of it the way I described even though the optimizer might actually do something else.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is finding the maximum area for countries.  Which countries?  All countries that match the continent of the country in the outer query.

So, for each country it gets the area of the largest country on the same continent.

The `WHERE` clause then says "are the two areas the same -- the maximum area and the area of this country?".  It chooses only countries that have the maximum area.

Comment: Thanks for your help